# How to output an constantly active CMD

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, append, output

I am running an application which opens CMD and connect via API service. Throughout the day new stuff will show up in the CMD and I would like to export that information to txt somewhere and Everytime something new shows up append to the same file, or create a new one. It doesn't really matter

App.exe > /file.txt doesn't really work

Comment: There are a number of articles that cover PowerShell and redirection. Yet, all things have their limits. You could just have whatever is the cmd controller create/add to a log file, that you can read later.

Answer (score 2):

Redirection examples

```
  command >  filename     # Redirect command output to a file (overwrite)
  command >> filename     # APPEND into a file
  command 2> filename     # Redirect Errors from operation to a file(overwrite)
  command 2>> filename    # APPEND errors to a file
  command 2>&1            # Add errors to results
  command 1>&2            # Add results to errors
  command | command       # This is the basic form of a PowerShell Pipeline

# In PowerShell 3.0+

  command 3> warning.txt  # Write warning output to warning.txt 
  command 4>> verbose.txt # Append verbose.txt with the verbose output 
  command 5>&1            # Writes debug output to the output stream 
  command *> out.txt      # Redirect all streams (output, error, warning, verbose, and debug) to out.txt
```

You are not showing any code as to how you are starting/using cmd.exe for your use case. Which just leaves folks trying to help you, to guess.  So, redirect of cmd.exe, for example:

```
$MyOutputFile = C:\MyOutputFile.txt
Start-Process -FilePath c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/c C:\YourCommand.bat' -Wait -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput $MyOutputFile
```

Lastly, since you've left us to guess. If you’re launching Process A from PowerShell, but it, Process A is, in turn, launching Process B, then it would be up to Process A to capture or redirect the output of Process B. There’s no way for PowerShell to sub-capture if Process A isn’t doing it.

Resources

- [About Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7)
- [How-to: Redirection](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-redirection.html)
- [PowerShell Redirection Operators](https://www.sconstantinou.com/powershell-redirection-operators)
- [Understanding Streams, Redirection, and Write-Host in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell)
- [Use PowerShell Redirection Operators for Script Flexibility](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-redirection-operators-for-script-flexibility)